# Laravel and nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

i have a question.

I have nginx as a web server, and laravel as MVC.

i use rewrited urls, but not simple, i use with suffixes.

when i use extension `.json` that is written in routes, laravel is executing it, but nginx returns 404 header with output of laravel.

my nginx code:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~* \.(ico|css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|woff) {
    expires 7d;
    root /www/system/public/;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    server_tokens  off;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

how can i tell to nginx that

Answer (score 1):

Request to `http://your.site/some.json` handled by `location /` and so doesn't passed to `php5-fpm`, nginx just returns or doesn't returns the file from `root` location what is most likely somewhere else in your configuration file. If you want to handle all requests to `*.json` by your PHP framework, you have to modify last location as follows:

```
location ~ \.(php|json)$
```

UPD: here is what happens according to log:

1. You request your.site/api/announce.json, nginx receives request
2. According to `/` location nginx tries to find $uri in `root` location, in your case `/www/system/public/api/announce.json`
3. Nginx throws 404 page, according to directive `error_page 404 /index.php;` it returns content of index.php (handled by your framework) with 404 code in header.

If you want this file to be passed as argument to Laravel, try to change `try_files` directive in `locaion /` as follows:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}
```

(according to my research this seems to be valid Laravel url you might want to use)

Comment: My framework does handle the request, but is nginx who doesen't return corect http code.

Comment: in other words, nginx does make request to php file, as is expected, but returns a 404 eror.

Comment: Please provide full URL which are you trying to reach, log entry for it's handling from nginx and php-fpm.

Comment: http://example.com/api/announce.json
#error.log
2015/01/30 15:44:16 [error] 3569#0: *10 open() "/www/system/public/api/announce.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: *.example.com, request: "GET /api/announce.json HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
#php-www
- -  01/Jan/1970:01:00:00 +0100 "GET /index.php" 200 /www/system/public/index.php 7296521.605 8704 0.00%